# Reinstall WordPress but keep WooCommerce

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, reinstall

I have recently taken over a Woocommerce webshop built by someone else. That someone else has done an incredibly bad job and now I am asked to clean up the mess.

After careful evaluation I came to the conclusion that the best solution is to start over on a clean install. There is a catch though: the shop has already about 5000 products! I tried to export/import but I got some issues on the way like exporting product images.

So, since the problems of the webshop are mainly on the WordPress itself and not on WooCommerce, I wonder if it is possible to make a clean re-install (files and DB) of WordPress but keep everything that concerns WooCommerce?

I have searched a lot about this but the only stuff I find is only about keeping WordPress and re-installing WooCommerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup your database first to do all these steps

> Go to `Tools > Exports`. here you will see post, products, variations, orders, e.t.c. Select what you want then click to Download Export file

Reinstall wordpress with new database and again

> Go to `Tools > Import`. Import file that you have exported.

If you don't have already installed any inporter plugin search any good importer plugin. Hope this will help

Comment: You may find it stupid (hope not) but when I export the images don't come along. Did I miss something?

Comment: The export is only an XML file. The images are referenced by their URLs and then downloaded from those URLs on import. I would consider cloning everything to a second site (see [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) or [WP Migrate Pro](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/)) and exporting the products from that site. Then when you go back to your principle site and chose to import the import process will download the media files from your backup site. You can't export WooCommerce settings this way though.